# To set the array delimiter to a newline in python

Tags: python

I just started learning python and I want to set the array delimiter to a newline in python script.

i know how to do it in shell script it is :

IFS=$'\n'

Comment: What's your input and expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

Code:

```
test = """line 0
line 1
line 2
line 3"""
arr = test.split("\n")
print(arr)
```

Output:

```
['line 0', 'line 1', 'line 2', 'line 3']
```